# does openmp allocate memory and free all after

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, openmp, valgrind

Does openmp allocate memory and free all memory? Because I ran valgrind, and did free all my lists.. Everything that I malloc, did I free.

```
==11442== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11442==     in use at exit: 192 bytes in 1 blocks
==11442==   total heap usage: 2,001 allocs, 2,000 frees, 2,917,280 bytes allocated
==11442== 
==11442== LEAK SUMMARY:
==11442==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11442==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11442==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11442==    still reachable: 192 bytes in 1 blocks
==11442==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

If not why can there still be a memory leak in one block?

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
/*check definition of _OPENMP*/
#ifdef _OPENMP
#include <omp.h>
#endif 

#define RMAX 10000000

/*Global variables*/
int arraySizeGlobal;
int numberOfthreads;
int *aux;

/*Functions*/
void sort(int *a);
void sort2(int *a, int lo, int hi);
void merge(int *a, int lo, int mid, int hi);
void Generate_list(int a[], int n);
void printlist(int *array);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
numberOfthreads = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
arraySizeGlobal = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10);
////////////////////////////////
int *array;
array = malloc(arraySizeGlobal * sizeof(int));
Generate_list(array,arraySizeGlobal);

printf("=====================\n");
printf("////Starting list////\n");
printf("=====================\n");
printlist(array);

sort(array);

printf("=====================\n");
printf("/////Sorted list/////\n");
printf("=====================\n");
printlist(array);

free(array);

return 0;
}

void sort(int *a)
{
aux = malloc(arraySizeGlobal * sizeof(int)); // Allocate space just once.
//#pragma omp parallel num_threads(numberOfthreads)
//#pragma omp single nowait
sort2(a, 0, arraySizeGlobal - 1);
free(aux);
}
void sort2(int *a, int lo, int hi)
{   // Sort a[lo..hi].
if (hi <= lo) return;
int mid = lo + (hi - lo)/2;
    #pragma omp parallel sections num_threads(numberOfthreads)
    {
    #pragma omp section
    sort2(a, lo, mid); // Sort left half.
    #pragma omp section
    sort2(a, mid+1, hi); // Sort right half.
    }

merge(a, lo, mid, hi); // Merge
}
void merge(int *a, int lo, int mid, int hi)
{   // Merge a[lo..mid] with a[mid+1..hi].
int i = lo, j = mid+1;
int k;
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(numberOfthreads)
for (k = lo; k <= hi; k++) // Copy a[lo..hi] to aux[lo..hi].
    aux[k] = a[k];
for (k = lo; k <= hi; k++) // Merge back to a[lo..hi].
    if (i > mid) a[k] = aux[j++];
    else if (j > hi ) a[k] = aux[i++];
    else if (aux[j] < aux[i]) a[k] = aux[j++];
    else a[k] = aux[i++];
}
void printlist(int *array)
{
int i;
for (i = 0; i < arraySizeGlobal; ++i)
{
    printf("%d ", array[i]);
}
printf("\n");
}
void Generate_list(int a[], int n) {
int i;
srandom(1);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    a[i] = random() % RMAX;
}  /* Generate_list */
```

==================================================================================

This code: Came from Algorithms FOURTH EDITION, Robert Sedgewick | Kevin Wayne.
It was a java implementation, which I change to a c implementation and paralyzed with openmp

==================================================================================

Comment: Rerun valgrind with `--leak-check=full` to see details about the leak.

Comment: hard to tell if you missed something without seeing code

Comment: +1 for using valgrind at all

Comment: @Mike added my code to the question. The more threads I run the more leaks I get.

Comment: what compiler/openmp library did you use?

Comment: I compiled with: gcc -g -O2 -Wall -fopenmp -o merge mergesort.c 
And it takes 2 arguments <Number of threads> and <The number of random numbers>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This highly depends on your compiler and openmp library implementation.

I tried your code with `gcc -fopenmp` version 4.4.6 (GCC) and `libgomp` 1.0.0 and i also get heap blocks which have not been deallocated. As far as I can tell `libgomp` does not kill it's spawned threads at the end of execution and makes the kernel clean up do this.

```
==85122== HEAP SUMMARY:
==85122==     in use at exit: 2,072 bytes in 4 blocks
==85122==   total heap usage: 203 allocs, 199 frees, 289,816 bytes allocated
==85122== 
==85122== 288 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 3 of 4
==85122==    at 0x4A05A28: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:467)
==85122==    by 0x3793A11792: _dl_allocate_tls (in /lib64/ld-2.12.so)
==85122==    by 0x379460701F: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so)
==85122==    by 0x4C15509: gomp_team_start (team.c:422)
==85122==    by 0x400BAA: sort2 (in /usr/users/ga002/lamzins/malloc_openmp)
==85122==    by 0x400B28: sort (in /usr/users/ga002/lamzins/malloc_openmp)
==85122==    by 0x400AAA: main (in /usr/users/ga002/lamzins/malloc_openmp)
==85122== 
==85122== LEAK SUMMARY:
==85122==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==85122==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==85122==      possibly lost: 288 bytes in 1 blocks
==85122==    still reachable: 1,784 bytes in 3 blocks
==85122==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==85122== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==85122== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
==85122== 
==85122== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==85122== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

When i compiled your code with `icc -openmp` Version 12.0.2 I got all allocated memory deallocated.

```
==85218== HEAP SUMMARY:
==85218==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==85218==   total heap usage: 841 allocs, 841 frees, 4,364,204 bytes allocated
==85218== 
==85218== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

**Edit:**
Also the issue you are describing is known and is not considered a memory leak: http://gcc.1065356.n5.nabble.com/Bug-libgomp-36298-New-gomp-contains-small-memoryleak-td330804.html

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I know now that its how you compile or with what you compile your code with that can cause memory leaks.

Comment: Found a report of this. It's an issue with `valgrind` and `libgomp` and is not a bug or memory leak.

Comment: Will add a +1 in the future. I can't add it yet

Comment: @Eagle, there is a check mark symbol beneath the +1/-1 arrows. If you consider this to be an answer to your question, click the check mark to mark the answer as such and to give Sergey reputation points.