# VC++: crash when freeing a DLL built with openMP

Tags: visual-c++, openmp, msvcrt

I've reduced a crash to the following toy code:

```
// DLLwithOMP.cpp : build into a dll *with* /openmp
#include <tchar.h>
extern "C"
{
   __declspec(dllexport)  void funcOMP()
   {
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        _tprintf(_T("Please fondle my buttocks\n"));
   }
}
```

_

```
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : build into an executable *without* /openmp

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

typedef void(*tDllFunc) ();

int main()
{
    HMODULE hDLL = LoadLibrary(_T("DLLwithOMP.dll"));
    tDllFunc pDllFunc = (tDllFunc)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "funcOMP");
    pDllFunc();
    FreeLibrary(hDLL);
    // At this point the omp runtime vcomp140[d].dll refcount is zero 
    // and windows unloads it, but the omp thread team remains active.
    // A crash usually ensues.
    return 0;
}
```

Is this an MS bug?  Is there some OMP thread-cleanup API I missed ([probably not](http://openmp.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=907), but maybe)? I don't have other compilers under hand. Do they treat this scenario differently? (again, [probably not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15660960/89706))  Does the OMP standard has anything to say on such a scenario?

Comment: Tried your code in VS2010, after `Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcomp100d.dll'` I do get a handful of Access Violations, after the `return 0`.  But when commenting out the `FreeLibrary`, then no Access Violations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got [an answer from Eric Brumer @ MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2158033/vc-crash-when-freeing-a-dll-built-with-openmp). Re-posting it here in case it is of interest to anyone in the future:

> for optimal performance, the openmp threadpool spin waits for about a
>   second prior to shutting down in case more work becomes available. If
>   you unload a DLL that's in the process of spin-waiting, it will crash
>   in the manner you see (most of the time).
>
> You can tell openmp not to spin-wait and the threads will immediately
>   block after the loop finishes. Just set OMP_WAIT_POLICY=passive in
>   your environment, or call SetEnvironmentVariable(L"OMP_WAIT_POLICY",
>   L"passive"); in your function before loading the dll. The default is
>   "active" which tells the threadpool to spin wait. Use the environment
>   variable, or just wait a few seconds before calling FreeLibrary.